# codeigniter .htaccess url issue

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter

I want to do this: (firstly, ci is my codeigniter folder)
If user call ci/2012.htm I want to redirect ci/oyna/oyun/2012.htm I'm trying to use this but It's not running.

```
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|resources|robots\.txt)
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L,QSA]
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/oyna/oyun/$1 [L,QSA]
```

When I call ci/2012.htm it returns codeigniter 404 not found page.

Comment: Is the line feed between `on` and `RewriteCond` missing in your real file, or just a copy/paste mistake?

Comment: I'm really new for htaccess. I need help.

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson copy/paste mistake :)

Comment: You may want to clarify your question a bit, are you trying to redirect all requests .htm files to static files in that folder and avoiding passing them through codeigniter (ie without passing them through index.php)?

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson when I call ci/oyna/oyun/2012.htm it returns true things.

Answer (score 1):

First; you have two rewriterules that conflict for the rewrite you're making;

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/oyna/oyun/$1 [L,QSA]
```

The `L` flag indicates that if a rule matches, the next rules won't be used. Since `2012.htm` matches the first rule (both rules match everything), it will be rewritten to `index.php/2012.htm` and stop there, not even getting to your oyna/oyun rewrite.

The solution would be to swap the rules and make the .htm rewrite more specific so it only rewrites .htm files. Changing the rule to;

```
RewriteRule ^(.*\.htm)$ index.php/oyna/oyun/$1 [L,QSA]
```

should work better.

The result, after putting the most selective rule first, should look something like (untested, no apache here)

**EDIT: Added missing RewriteCond, you need one per RewriteRule**

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|robots\.txt)
RewriteRule ^(.*\.htm)$ index.php/oyna/oyun/$1 [L,QSA]
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|robots\.txt)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: Result: Internal Server Error ?

Comment: @user1648692 Sorry, added a missing RewriteCond, there needs to be one per RewriteRule.

Comment: same. And now it can't reach css files.

Comment: @user1648692 Depending on where your css files are stored (and at what path they're fetched), you may need to put back the `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f`and `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d`. And with "same", do you mean internal server error? I just got to a machine where I could test the setup and with a cut'n'paste from above I get the correct redirect without any errors.